# Displaying Menu items through webview in android application

Tags: android, html, web-applications, webview

I am new to Android application development and still learning. I have created a simple web app using webview and that is working well now I have created a menu in my app and trying to add an about and help and exit item on that. Now I would like them to open inside another webview or the existing webview that I have created. I am confused that should I create another method or a class or another way you prefer
I mean when I will choose `about` from menu then I will be redirected to a page in my asset folder called about.html and for `help` it will be help.html .

this is my MainActivity.java

```
package com.example.mywebapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.Window;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView mWebView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        mWebView = new WebView(this);
        mWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        view.loadUrl(url);
        return true;
        }
        });

        this.setContentView(mWebView);
    }

    // For Options Menu
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.about:
        // Then it should redirect to "file:///android_asset/about.html"
        return true;
        case R.id.help:
        // Then it will be redirect to "file:///android_asset/help.html"
        return true;
        case R.id.exit:
        finish();
        return true;
        default:
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(final int keyCode, final KeyEvent event) {
        if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack()) {
        mWebView.goBack();
        return true;
        }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```

And my main.xml from layout folder

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <WebView
        android:id="@+id/webView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Please dont down vote if you dont know how to do this or dont have any ans for it .. plz ...

Answer (score 0):

Found a solution

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.about:
    startActivity(new Intent(this, About.class));
    return true;
    case R.id.exit:
    finish();
    return true;
    default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
```

and then creating a About.class with these code

```
package com.example.mywebapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class About extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.about);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView);
        //webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        //webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

        webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/about.html");

    }

}
```

and finally in AndroidManifest

```
 <activity
        android:name=".About"
        android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar" />
```

i hope this ans would help newbie like me ...